# Настройка Apache+Kerberos+WSGI+ALD Ошибки аутентификации и чтения скрипта

Tags: apache2, wsgi, astra-linux, kerberos

На Astra Linux 1.6 пытаюсь настроить вывод мандатных меток в браузер. При выключенном Astra Mode выдает дефолтную страницу Apache "it`s works!", при включенном index.html. Тоесть WSGI ни в какую работать не хочет, пробовала с разными скриптами.

Логи:
Apache

```
astra_mode - ap_invoke_handler: user name is not set, referer: http://aldserver.name.ru/
Authentication not configured
```

Kerberos:

```
NEEDED_PREAUTH: user@NAME.RU for krbtgt/NAME.RU@NAME.RU, Additional pre-authentication required
```

Конфиг Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # имя web-сервера
        ServerName aldserver.name.ru 
 
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        # директория, в котором лежат скрипты приложения
        DocumentRoot /var/www/name.ru
 
        # указываем, какой скрипт запускать при обращении к aldserver.name.ru/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/name.ru/app.wsgi 
 
        # настройки для корректной авторизации через Kerberos
        <Directory /var/www/name.ru>
                AuthType Kerberos
                KrbAuthRealms REALM
                KrbServiceName HTTP/aldserver.name.ru
                Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/keytab
                KrbMethodNegotiate on
                KrbMethodK5Passwd off
                KrbSaveCredentials on
                require valid-user
        </Directory>
         
        # для откладки
        LogLevel debug
 
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 
</VirtualHost>
```

App.wsgi:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from os import getuid
sys.path.insert(0, 'var/www/name.ru')
 
def application(env, start_response):
        status = '200 OK'
        id = subprocess.check_output(['pdp-id'])
  
        output = "UID: " + str(getuid()) + "<br/><br/>" + id # возвращаем uid пользователя, заупустившего процесс и его мандатные атрибуты
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'), ('Encoding', 'utf-8'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]  # заголовки ответа
 
        start_response(status, response_headers)
 
        return [output]
```

В чем косяк? Пользователь введен в ALD, захожу на клиентскую машину с него. В браузере параметры negotiate прописаны.

Comment: Ну как это делается на астра линукс я не в курсе, но знаю что билет кербероса выдается не просто общий, а на сервис, в домене для прокси или апача он начинается на HTTP/server.fqdn@DOMAIN.FQDN и чтобы это работало надо еще в файле /etc/krb5.conf указать файл для хранения кейтабов и дать права на чтение тому же апачу ну и создать кейтаб для сервиса тоже. если хотите могу глянуть конфиг для авторизации на апаче через керберос, как то давно делал. но правда он для виндового домена был. будут мелкие отличия. Еще нужно чтобы шло время правильно, и в днс имя компа соотв. имени в билете.

Comment: Я так понимаю следующие команды и делают перечисленное вами, они были выполнены при установке :                                                                                       ald-client update-svc-keytab HTTP/aldserver.name.ru --ktfile="/etc/apache2/keytab "           chown www-data /etc/apache2/keytab                                                                                           chmod 644 /etc/apache2/keytab

Comment: а в файле /etc/krb5.conf как и где указываются keytab? Там сейчас нет упоминаний чего-то похожего. Про время спасибо! как на виртуальных машинах иногда слетает, буду иметь в виду. Конфиг если не сложно гляньте))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось! Для этого потребовалось:

1. Отвязать дефолтный конфиг апача в /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

> sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

Привязать свой через a2ensite, если не был привязан.

2. В конфинге керберос явно указать файл keytab

/ect/krb5.conf

> [libdefaults]
> default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/apache2/keytab

3. Убрать все комментарии в скрипте wsgi.

Profit!)

Comment: думаю тут главное правильно прописать права на файл кейтаба и четко зафиксировать его положение в системе, ну и тикет чтобы был так же сформирован корректно + время бралось из одного источника + имена в днс чтобы соотв. IP-адресам. больше всего проблем именно в этом. я тоже когда в сквиде делал авторизацию через керберос + лдап много на эти нюансы времени потратил. зато работает потом как часы.

Comment: удивительно, но на данный момент krb5.conf без добавленной мной строчки (видимо ald перегенерировал этот файл) и все все равно работает. Магия.

Answer (score 1):

внутри файла /etc/krb5.conf добавить ссылку на файл кейтаба. примонтировать корень с опцией acl (в /etc/fstab и ребут или ремаунт), через setfacl добавить право на чтение кейтаба юзеру под которым у вас запущен апач или другой веб-сервер, к примеру www-data.
создать кейтаб в зависимости от вашего окружения ( у меня домен MS я делал через net ads keytab) если у вас линуксовый KDC то там немного по-другому, но суть такая же.
если все правильно сделаете у вас будет примерно такой же вывод.
обратите внимание, что у вас должен быть билет для службы в правильном формате (HTTP/server.full.name.com@DOMAIN.FULL.NAME.COM), иначе ракета не полетит. Будьте внимательны к регистру символов в реалме(имя домена после @) если написать в нижнем регистре не все библиотеки и приложения на это нормально реагируют.

```
klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 host/server_name.domain.name@DOMAIN.NAME
   3 host/server_name@DOMAIN.NAME
   3 HTTP/server_name.domain.name@DOMAIN.NAME
   3 HTTP/server_name@DOMAIN.NAME
```

/ect/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
        default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
```

в конфиге апача

```
<Location /some_location>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AuthType Kerberos
    KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.FULL.NAME.COM
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd off
    Krb5Keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
    KrbServiceName HTTP/server.full.name.com@DOMAIN.FULL.NAME.COM
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: да еще на стороне клиента тоже через klist проверьте, что у вас выдался нормальный билет (если это не виндовые машины).

Comment: что отличает ненормальный билет? Их там три, для krbtgt/NAME.RU@NAME.RU , для ldap/aldserver.name.ru@NAME.RU , для cifs/aldserver.name.ru@NAME.RU.

Comment: согласно документации астры, Krb5KeyTab все таки должен лежать в /etc/apache2/keytab. Правда при klist -k он выдает только HTTP/... принципиалы, а хоста нет. Пробовала перевязать на krb5.keytab, там есть и хост и HTTP, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: все сделала, ничего не изменилось. Сейчас отвязала дефолтный конфиг в sites-enabled. теперь на клиенте ошибка "Unathorized". Логи практически те же, добавилось только строчка в логах кербероса "no dictionary file specified continuing without on out one"